# Installing tk/tcl on an existing ruby 2.2 installation in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-14.04, tk-toolkit

I saw some fix for previous versions of ruby, unfortunately, it doesn't work anymore for 2.2... Is there a way to add it up to my existing installation, or should I do a reinstall so I can configure ruby to include tk/tcl? Anyways, I'm using rbenv as my version manager.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue as I think you have(/had?). I'm running ruby 2.2 on ubuntu 14.04 installed using rbenv. When I tried

```
require 'tk'
```

I got:

```
cannot load such file -- tk
```

After a lot of fidgeting around I finally made it work by downloading ActiveTCL from http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads (I got version 8.6.4), unpacked it and installed it using

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

I also added the bin folder of ActiveTcl to my path (updated my ~/.profile), on my installation it is: /opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/bin/

then uninstalling the ruby version using

```
rbenv uninstall 2.2.2
```

And reinstalling it using

```
rbenv install 2.2.2
```

After that I can now require tk and not get any error.